# How to calculate a power using an array as "base" and a dataframe row as "exponent"?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given an "array" with `lenght == n (here n=3)`

```
a = [10,100,1000]
```

and a Pandas dataframe with n columns

```
df = DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...])
```

how can I have the array to the power of each dataframe row?

```
res = [[10**1, 100**2, 1000**3],
      [10**4, 100**5, 1000**6], ...]
```

Comment: Please show us how you approach this problem.

Comment: a**df is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with NumPy, you can do:

```
a = np.array([10,100,1000])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

a ** df.values

rray([[                 10,               10000,          1000000000],
       [              10000,         10000000000, 1000000000000000000]],
```